# Save RichTextBox At text file or word file

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox, dialog, richtextbox

iam a small coder and i need help to save 2 of RichTextBox data in word file

Look At This Pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6dfW.png

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    On Error Resume Next
    RichTextBox3.LoadFile("C:\Windows\Help\enter.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    RichTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\Windows\Help\out.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
End Sub


 Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "save"
        dlg.FileName = "log out " & DateString
        dlg.Filter = "Word (*.doc)|*.doc"
        If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception : End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "save"
        dlg.FileName = "log enter " & DateString
        dlg.Filter = "Word (*.doc)|*.doc"
        If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox3.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception : End Try
End Sub
```

i cant coder the button at the pic (( Indicated by the arrow ))

If You Need The Source Code : https://www.mediafire.com/?6du52ybx5d8vyts

i hope help :(

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to be saved in text or word format? I suggest using text here.

Comment: ok but how to do this ???

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` causes the file to be saved in Rich Text format, so you can name it with an extension of .rtf and it can be read by Word. You can also save it with `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` with a .txt extension and it can be read by Word. There's not an automatic way to save it as a .docx or .doc file.

You can combine the two rich text boxes like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, RichTextBox1.rtf & vbcrlf & RichTextBox3.rtf)

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, RichTextBox1.txt & vbcrlf & RichTextBox3.txt)
```

Comment: what about save the file as a pdf file ??

Comment: This is not provided in .net.

Comment: Well Can I save a file in Word in order to be protected is not adjustable??